# How to display an entire queue struct

Tags: c, struct, queue

I designed a circular queue program which provides queue management system. Everything works fine, except that in some cases, I can't print the queue.

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define CAPACITY 5
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 40
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0


struct queue
 {
 char items[CAPACITY][MAX_STRING_SIZE]; 
 int front,rear ;
 };
 
void cqinsert(struct queue * , char name[]);
void cqdelete(struct queue *);
int empty(struct queue *);


int main(void)
{
int order;
char name[MAX_STRING_SIZE]; 
int menu;
    
char operation;
int x;
struct queue q;
q.front = q.rear = CAPACITY - 1;
 


do{
    printf(">>Please enter an operation number from the given list:\n");
    printf("[1]-Customer Entry\n[2]-Customer Exit\n[3]-Waiting Customers List\n[4]-Exit\n");
    scanf("%d",&menu);
    switch(menu) {
        case 1: printf("Enter customer name: ");
                scanf("%s",&name);
                cqinsert(&q,name);
                break;
        
        case 2: cqdelete(&q);
                break;
        
        case 3: if(q.front==CAPACITY-1) {
            
                order = 1;
                    for(int i=0;i<=q.rear;i++) {    
                        printf("[%d]-%s\n",order,q.items[i]);
                        order++;
                    }
                break;
                }
                
                else {
                    order=1;
                    for(int i=q.front+1;i<=q.rear;i++) {
                    
                        printf("[%d]-%s\n",order,q.items[i]);
                        order++;
                    }
                break;
                }
                            
        
        
    }
}while(menu!=4);


system("pause");
return 0;
}


int empty(struct queue *pq)
{
return((pq->front == pq->rear) ? TRUE : FALSE);
}


void cqdelete(struct queue *pq)
{
    
if (empty(pq)) {
printf("Queue is empty !");
exit(1);
}

if (pq->front == CAPACITY - 1)
 pq->front = 0;
 
else
 (pq->front)++;
 
printf("\n -----> %s is deleted from the queue. \n\n",pq->items[pq->front]);

}


void cqinsert(struct queue *pq , char name[])
{
 printf("\n -----> %s is inserted to queue. \n\n",name);
if (pq->rear == CAPACITY - 1)
pq->rear = 0;
else
(pq->rear)++;
if (pq->rear == pq->front) {
 printf("Queue is full !");
 exit(1);
 }

strcpy(pq->items[pq->rear],name);
 }
```

When `q.front` is greater than `q.rear`, `case 3` (the printing) doesn't print anything.

**For example** after the inputs below I can't display queue elements:

- 4 times CUSTOMER ENTRY(insert)
- 2 times CUSTOMER EXIT(delete)
- 2 times CUSTOMER ENTRY(insert)
- and select *Waiting Customers List* ---> here is the problem: it doesn't display elements in the queue.

You can use the following inputs to apply those steps:

```
1
c1
1
c2
1
c3
1
c4
2
2
1
c5
1
c6
3
4
```

How can I display the queue, even when `q.front` is greater than `q.rear`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your suggestion, let's see what happens when we insert 4 customers, then remove 2, then insert 2 more:

Initially:

```
rear = 4
front = 4
queue:
 +----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
 |          |          |          |          |          |
 +----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

After 4 inserts:

```
rear = 3
front = 4
queue:
 +----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
 |   "c1"   |   "c2"   |   "c3"   |   "c4"   |          |
 +----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

After 2 deletes:

```
rear = 3
front = 1
queue:
 +----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
 |          |          |   "c3"   |   "c4"   |          |
 +----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

After 2 more inserts:

```
rear = 0
front = 1
queue:
 +----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
 |   "c6"   |          |   "c3"   |   "c4"   |   "c5"   |
 +----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

To print this queue, you wrote this piece of code (we are in the `else` of the `case 3` since `q.front` is not `CAPACITY-1`):

```
order=1;
for(int i=q.front+1;i<=q.rear;i++) {
  printf("[%d]-%s\n",order,q.items[i]);
  order++;
}
```

`i` is initialized at `q.front+1 = 2`. The looping condition is `i<=q.rear`. Since `q.rear` is 0, this means `i<=0`. This is already false before the first iteration since `2<=0` is false. Thus, nothing gets printed.

Informally, the way to print the queue is:

- print `c3` (index = `q.front + 1`)
- print `c4` (index = `q.front + 2`)
- print `c5` (index = `q.front + 3`)
- print `c6` (index = `(q.front + 4) % CAPACITY`)

See what I did for `c6`? I wrapped around to the beginning of the queue by doing `% CAPACITY`. In fact, I could have added this `% CAPACITY` to all the other cases, it just wouldn't have changed anything since `q.front+1`/`q.front+2`/`q.front+3` are less than `CAPACITY`.

In your code, you thought about wrapping around, but only when `q.front` is `CAPACITY-1`. Instead, you should *always* consider wrapping around. To do so, you can write the `case 3` as follows (this is simply the algorithm corresponding to the informal steps I wrote above):

```
case 3:
  for (int i = q.front; i != q.rear; i = (i+1) % CAPACITY) {
    int order = (i+1-q.front+CAPACITY) % CAPACITY; // (... + CAPACITY) % CAPACITY ensures a positive number
    printf("[%d]-%s\n", order, q.items[(i+1) % CAPACITY]);
  }
  break;
```

The idea is to start from `q.front` and continue looping until `i` is `q.rear`. However, while looping, we wrap around by doing `i = (i+1) % CAPACITY` instead of `i++`.

Note how `q.front==CAPACITY-1` is not a special case anymore: this loop will wrap around, regardless the value of `q.front`.

Comment: Hey man, I have another question: When I add 5th element to the queue it doesn't show up while case 3 working. I'd been trying but couldn't work it out. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Furkan the problem is that when front == rear, with your current implementation, you don't know if the queue is full or if it's empty. That's what you need to fix ;)